# How to purge all celery subtasks from parent task?

Tags: python-2.7, celery, celery-task

In my `sharedtask` I call several `subtasks(...).apply_async()`. Thus, both the parent task and the subtasks have their own task_id.

When I cancel the entire operation, I call the revoke of all active tasks and it works correctly. But as soon as cores are released, the queue moves on, executing the next subtasks.

How do I programmatically clear the queue, thereby preventing the next subtasks from being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

and start the task with:

```
task_id = subtasks(...).apply_async()
```

I'm not sure if it works with subtasks to save the task id in this way, but with normal tasks it works well, so it is worth trying.